# Finding average for columns with two values in pivot tables

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have created a pivot table with column labels having two values (i.e "YES" or "NO") and it also provides a grand total on the next column.

I am trying to figure out a way to find the averages for the two values with respect to the grand total.

Here is my table:
[image]

Comment: See this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-a-percentage-for-subtotals-in-a-PivotTable-6aa66bce-11c5-47f7-b6b6-0959b0b13a72

Comment: Thanks! Will look into it.